# Failure of GCH at a strongly compact cardinal

Tags: lo.logic, set-theory, forcing

Does **Con(ZFC+ there exists a strongly compact cardinal)** imply **Con(ZFC+ there exists a strongly compact cardinal $\kappa+ 2^\kappa > \kappa^+$)**?

Comment: Won't such a theorem prove GCH fails above a strongly compact cardinal? (Because if $2^\kappa>\kappa^+$, why not make it \kappa^{+3}$?)

Comment: I don't see any problem, what you suggested can happen for a supercompact cardinal for example. Maybe you are referring to Solovay's theorem, but what I'm asking does not contradict it.

Comment: The main point of my question is to give such a result from just a strongly compact cardinal. Note that a supercompact cardinal is clearly an upper bound; but we do not know if strongly compact cardinals and supercompact cardinals are equiconsistent.

Comment: This is a bit old question, but I was wondering, can't we apply an argument similar to Hamkins' Indestrubitility Theorem 4.1 in his paper "Lottery Preparation"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer to the question is yes, as it is proved by Usuba in the paper
[Strongly compact cardinals and the continuum function](https://arxiv.org/abs/1901.05313)
.

In fact Usuba proves the following more general result:

**Theorem**. Assume $\kappa$ is a strongly compact cardinal. Then there exists a generic extension in which $\kappa$ remains strongly compact and indestructible under adding any number of new subsets to $\kappa$ (Theorem 3.1 of the above paper).